# Unrecognized selector sent to instance IOS 10

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash

I have a very difficult problem when I launched my app on IOS10.3.3.. Indeed, I got this error in my splashviewController :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // [[EMAnalyticsManager sharedInstance]sendScreenViewWithName:SplashScreen];
}
```

I got this crash message:

```
[__NSCFString nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165e3630
2018-09-06 16:57:31.456059+0100 **********[2461:1072580] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165e3630'
```

I made many research to understand the cause of this crash that didn't occur in IOS11.

Any help please??

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint, run again, and add the code around where the exception occurred into this question....https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/294949

Answer (score 0):

Some constraints might be causing this when the very first view controller is loaded. Please check your constraint and you can also remove the constraints and then verify if it works.